# What do all of these symbols mean on an old power factor meter?

Tags: power-factor-correction

"cos. phi" is OK, it's a power factor meter. Apart from that; from the top left, I understand "Klasse 1,5" to mean max. 1.5% measurement error, 5A to mean maximum 5A I guess. On the right, I understand 110V to mean expected voltage 110VAC. Can anyone help with the rest?

[image]

Comment: I suspect 1/50 (or whatever that is) means 50Hz. DS is for Dansk (Danish) Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the rest of the symbols not already discussed in the question and comments:

The star with 2, means 2kV insulation test voltage.
The 3 sines stand for a three-phase AC system.
The symbol on the left of the star, means "electrodynamic iron-less ratiometer".